# mmap memory alignment in ARM

Tags: c++, arm, mmap, qnx, sigbus

I'm working on a project that's being ported to ARM7 (was originally on x86). It runs on QNX. We've had a few memory alignment issues (SIGBUS error crashes) due to reading/writing with misaligned pointers. I've been fixing most alignment issues simply by replacing the pointer casting and assignment with a memcpy, but this issue I can't solve like that.

There's a memory pool shared between processes that's initialized like this:

```
int m_nSharedMemory = shm_open(EVENT_LIST_NAME, O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0777);
ftruncate(m_nSharedMemory, nSize)
unsigned char* m_pMemory = (unsigned char*) mmap(0, nSize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, m_nSharedMemory, 0);
```

The memory is supposed to be used like this: there's a `Header` at the beginning of the address space and there's an `Event` array afterwards. Thus, `nSize = sizeof(Header) + MAX_EVENTS * sizeof(Event)`.

```
m_pHeader = (Header*)m_pMemory;
m_pEvents = (Event*)(m_pMemory + sizeof(Header));
```

Both `Header` and `Event` are structs with primitive types. As far as I know, this memory is not aligned, so doing `m_pEvents[0].m_SomeField == 3` or `m_pHeader->m_SomeField = 1` could potentially trigger a SIGBUS error. This kind of instructions are everywhere, so replacing each one with memcpy would be a real pain, I'm hoping I can get away with something else.

I've found `posix_memalign` which I believe could replace either `shm_open` or `mmap`, not sure which yet, but this doesn't seem to solve the issue either. For one, I still get the warning. Even ignoring the warning, I could make sure memory is aligned to `sizeof(Header)`, but `m_pEvents` wouldn't be aligned.

Is there any way to prevent a SIGBUS error without making major modifications to this scheme? Right now the compiler is complaining because `"cast from 'unsigned char*' to 'Header*' increases required alignment of target type"` (there's a similar warning for `Event`), but the program is not crashing, which I really can't explain.

So, two questions: 1) Why doesn't it crash? 2) How do I make sure it never will, ideally by ensuring that memory is aligned and supressing the warning

Comment: did you mean armv7 or arm7?  You are pointing at ram, basically crossing a compile domain, there is no way to insure that it never will crash (well you can disable alignment checking and the result varies between armv7 and arm7) this kind of programming style will always have this problem, so you will always have to maintain this code if/when you re-compile this.

Comment: elementary pointer math will put you on the right starting alignment if you need to align on an 8 byte boundary (64 bit) then you allocate 7 or 8 extra bytes and adjust the pointer that comes back from the alloc.  beyond that if you are using structures then it is a lifetime maintenance problem.

Comment: Change `Header` to be aligned to 32/64bits or add padding to `nSize` and align `m_pEvents`.  [`(m_pMemory + sizeof(Header) + 7) & ~7`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2022179/c-quick-calculation-of-next-multiple-of-4)  You should read the `FSR` (fault status register) to see if it is an alignment or permission issue.

Comment: you can prevent crashing, but cant insure working.

Comment: @artlessnoise, awesome, we ask interview candidates about alignment and almost none, well actually none, including most employees, get it down to that simple solution.   most do modulo with an if and add, others do mask with an if and add, nice to see this...

Comment: @old_timer My target in gcc is `PLT_ARM7LE`, not sure if that answers the question. What I want to do is prevent SIGBUS crashes, whether the code works or not is an issue for another day.

Comment: @artlessnoise I got the solution for `m_pEvents`. Still not getting the one for `Header`. What do you mean change it to be aligned to 32/64? `Header` will start wherever mmap chooses to align m_pMemroy. Maybe I should add that `nSize = sizeof(Header) + MAX_EVENTS * sizeof(Event)`

Comment: nope doesnt help.  artless noise has simply given you the fish on this one rather than let you learn to fish.  you have to start with getting the beginning alignment right then depending on structures vs just an array of some power of two size (bytes, halfwords, words, doublewords) you may have more work.  structures can land somewhere between preventing crashing or not or always working based on how you declare them and their content and pack them.  if packed up nicely you can check the sizeof at runtime before using and bail out if it is not right.

Comment: no reason you have to use the pointer that comes back from mmap as is you can start a few bytes into that, that is the point.

Comment: if you are pointing at something in memory used by something else then of course you have to use the beginning pointer address as is, but then you have to deal with trying to re-align things, if they dont fall on a nice boundary then you have to pull them apart in bytes and build up whatever you are after...