# Find the next leap year in C

Tags: c, leap-year

I'm having trouble with an exercise on my homework.
I have to make a function that tells me when the next leap year is given an `n` (or `n` if it's a leap year).

I already tackled the last part, but I'm having trouble with the "next leap year" part. I assume I have to do a cycle?

Here's what I have so far

```
int next_leapyear(int n) 
{

    if(((n%4==0)&&(n%100!=0))||(n%400==0)) return n;

    else
    while(?){
      n++;
     }

     return n;
}
```

I'm just starting to learn this language, so if you guys could keep it simple I would appreciate it

Comment: `while(/* n is not leap year */){ n++; } return n;`

Comment: ... and no need for the first `if ... else`.

Comment: yeah makes sense
anyway, I just have to negate the first part in my `while()` right?
Im not sure how to do it but Ill try to find the answer, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Increase `n` until your `if` statement condition is not true so there are 2 ways either you can put condition in while braces, which is straight forward.

2nd is that, run loop infinite times and put breaking condition inside the loop

```
while(1){
      n++;
if(((n%4==0)&&(n%100!=0))||(n%400==0)) break;

     }
```

Comment: I didnt learn the `1` in a cycle at class yet, but I assume its the logic value "true", so the cycle keeps going until the `if` is satisfied? (and obviously `break` stops the cycle)

Anyway that solved my issue, thank you very much!

Comment: Yes you got it right. keep learning!

Comment: Why would you make a while loop with an always-true conditional and then have an if-statement to break out of it when you could just use that if statement as the conditional?

Comment: For calculating next leap year(if current is not leap) we have to reach at that year for satisfying if condition, by increment n by 1 every time.

Comment: your indentation is not good, and we don't actually need to increase n by 1 every time to reach the next leap year

Answer (score 3):

The task could be split into two parts. First, one could check whether a given `n` is a leap year, which coule be done with the following function.

```
int IsLeapYear(int n)
{
    return (((n%4==0)&&(n%100!=0))||(n%400==0));
}
```

Next, one could use a loop, based on the function above, to increase `n` until it is a leap year. This could be done as follows.

```
int GetNextLeapYear(int n)
{
    int CurrentYear = n;
    while(!IsLeapYear(CurrentYear))
    {
        CurrentYear++;
    }
    return CurrentYear;
}
```

Comment: Got it! But my exercise asked for a single function for both parts. I learnt a lot from what you said though, thanks

Comment: @Tiago Araújo your unknown exercise may have asked for a single function for both part, but the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46746157/2410359) did not.  This answer outlines a clear solution, it is the better approach to coding.

Answer (score 2):

Your idea of increasing the year until it's a leap year *will work* but it's not very efficient because you have to do a lot of modulos which is a **very expensive** operations.

In fact to find the next normal leap year you just need to **round the year to the [next multiple of 4](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2022179/995714)**, which can be achieved with either of these

```
year = (year + 3) & ~0x03;
year = (year | 0x03) + 1;
```

In case the after rounded it's a multiple of 100 then just add 4 to get the correct year. So the implementation may be like this

```
int next_leapyear(int n)
{
    n = (n + 3) & ~3;
    if (n % 100 == 0) n += 4;
    return n;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.